# Matplotlib sliding window not plotting correctly

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a code that runs a rolling window (30) average over a range (i.e. 300)

So I have 10 averages but they plot against ticks 1-10 rather than spaced over every window of 30.

The only way I can get it to look right is to plot it over (len(windowlength)) but the x-axis isnt right.

Is there any way to manually space the results?

[image]

```
windows30 = (sliding_window(sequence, 30))                                         

Overall_Mean = mean(sequence)                                         

fig, (ax) = plt.subplots()  
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, bottom=0.08, right=0.96, top=0.92, wspace=0.20, hspace=0.23)

ax.set_ylabel('mean (%)')
ax.set_xlabel(' Length')  # axis titles
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(windows30, color='r', marker='o', markersize=3)
ax.plot([0, len(sequence)], [Overall_Mean, Overall_Mean], lw=0.75)


plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the type of `windows30`? Whatever it is, it provides both your x and y values for your plot. The easiest way would be to only use the y-values from the `windows30` variable and a list of equally spaced points, from 0 to 300, as your x-values.

Comment: Its a list of mean values based on the window size requested (30). So if I have a length 300, I have 10 values. How would I only use the y values and assign them to incrementing values of 30 on the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood you have a list of length 300 but only holds 10 values inside. If that is the case, you can remove the other values that are `None` from your `windows30` list using the following solution.

### Code Demonstration:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generating the list of Nones and numbers
listofzeroes = [None] * 290
numbers = random.sample(range(50), 10)
numbers.extend(listofzeroes)

# Removing Nones from the list
numbers = [value for value in numbers if value is not None]  
step = len(numbers)
x_values = np.linspace(0,300,step)  # Generate x-values

plt.plot(x_values,numbers, color='red', marker='o')
```

This is a working example, the relevant code for you is after the second comment.

### Output:

[image: example-image]

The above code will work independently of where the `Nones` are located in your list. I hope this solves your problem.